# Consuming workflow service (WF 4) operations with async/await keywords

Tags: wcf, async-await, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

Is there an easy way to consume operations exposed by a workflow service (WF 4) so that I can use the async keyword from a service client?

Service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<int> GetSomething();
}
```

Usage:

```
var service = GetChannel<IMyService>();
var result = await service.GetSomething();
```

How can I implement the channel with and (if needed) the Receive/Send reply activities in the workflow service?

Remark: I would like to avoid the automatic generation of the proxies.

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to avoid the automatic generation of the proxies."?

Comment: I mean the "add service reference" dialog in visual studio

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you want to build the proxy classes by hand?

Comment: I prefer to inherit from ChannelBase<T> or create a channel with ChannelFactory<T>

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Try generating a proxy with add service reference and see how it implements the `Task`-based APIs.